# Firebase FCM send notification OnMessageReceived PendingIntent show current activity

Tags: android, firebase-notifications

I have an app with several activities. I am implenting Firecbase FCM and it all works pretty well except in handling which activity to go to when the user clicks on the notification icon when it is received.

As I'm not sure how/when the FirebaseMessagingService is instantiated I cannot set it up with access to any of my objects. The only thingI have been able to do is to store the current Activity in the App as

```
public static Activity CurrentActivity { get; set; }
```

I then set the above in the OnCreate() of each activity, then in FirebaseMessagingService .OnMessageReceived() I setup my pending intent as below:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, App.CurrentActivity.GetType());

        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);           

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, App.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, App.CHANNEL_ID)
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notification)
                                  .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
                                  .SetContentText("test")
                                  .SetAutoCancel(true)    //dismisses the notification on click
                                  .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(App.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

This works in so far so when the user clicks on the Notification it goes to the correct activity.

The problem is if a notification is recevied when the user is in Activity A but doesn't click on it and moves to Activity B and then clicks on the notification. My Pending Intent will be Activity A. However after the Notification is shown, Activity A is then displayed.

I was thinking if it is possible in OnMessageReceived() to detect is the app is in foreground or background then if in foreground I could just do and intent to display an Alert Dialog of the message and if in background then my original code would work fine.

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible and how?

Comment: Define a Static Variable and change its value in onResumt() and onPause() to detect it.

Comment: Update: I have managed to sort this out. For anyone else who has a similar problem in my FirebaseMessagingService.OnMessageReceived()  I created a PendingIntent to a standard activity called NotificationActivity. I extracted the sent the body and title from the message parameter and passed it to NotificationActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to sort this out so thought I would post an update for anyone else who has a similar problem.

In my FirebaseMessagingService.OnMessageReceived()  I created a PendingIntent to a standard activity called NotificationActivity.

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
```

From **message** I extracted the body and title and passed to NotificationActivity

NotificationActivity.OnCreate() will then just display an AlertDialog and on the OK click I closed the activity using `this.Finish()`

This works perfectly when the user receives a notification when in the app. The user can click on the notification and it will show the  AlertDialog. On close it just resumes on whatever was the current activity.

Comment: just a question about when app is in background or killed. How does pendingIntent help in that case?

Comment: I don't have the code handy to test but from memory but it shows a Notification Icon at top and when you drag down and select it would bring the app to the foreground (if backgrounded). I'm pretty sure it would also start off the app if it had been killed (but I'll test that when back in work)